# rails console command is giving an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I am new to rails and when i tried to run rails console from my root it is giving below error...

```
harsha@Trebuchet:~/simp_cms$ rails console
/home/harsha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:39: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
/home/harsha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:78: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
/home/harsha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
    from /home/harsha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/harsha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/harsha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/harsha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require'
    from /home/harsha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
    from /home/harsha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:58:in `console'
    from /home/harsha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/harsha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

My ruby & ROR version details are mentioned below

```
harsha@Trebuchet:~/simp_cms$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
harsha@Trebuchet:~/simp_cms$ rails --version
/home/harsha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:39: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
/home/harsha/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:78: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
Rails 4.2.2
harsha@Trebuchet:~/simp_cms$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.2.2)
actionpack (4.2.2)
actionview (4.2.2)
activejob (4.2.2)
activemodel (4.2.2)
activerecord (4.2.2)
activesupport (4.2.2)
arel (6.0.0)
bigdecimal (1.2.7, 1.2.6)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.10.5)
columnize (0.9.0)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.8)
erubis (2.7.0)
globalid (0.3.5)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.3, 1.8.1)
loofah (2.0.2)
mail (2.6.3)
mime-types (2.6.1)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.7.0, 5.4.3)
mysql2 (0.3.18)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
power_assert (0.2.3, 0.2.2)
psych (2.0.13, 2.0.8)
rack (1.6.4)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.2)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
railties (4.2.2)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
sdoc (0.4.1)
spring (1.3.6)
sprockets (3.2.0)
sprockets-rails (2.3.2)
test-unit (3.1.2, 3.0.8)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
web-console (2.1.3)
harsha@Trebuchet:~/simp_cms$
```

Please suggest me what i eed to do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're running a version of ruby with no Readline support
Please `gem install rb-readline` or recompile ruby --with-readline.
So after installing it with gem install rb-readline and confirming the installation was sucessful with:

Add `gem 'rb-readline'` to your Gemfile and it should work.

Comment: I just edited the answer, @AkshayChavan actually answered the question. And you can accept the answer.